# I cannot return the value in my function(discount and mPrice)

Tags: function, return

When I run this code the value in the function is suppose to change the value output is wrong,it does not include the discount i calculated in the function for its final answer.I want the code to return the value in the function so the discount can be applied for final price and membership card price can be added to the total value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
float hotelMembership(char );
int main()
{
    float qRoom,tRoom[4]={15,15,15,10},sRoom[4],aRoom[4];
    char mem,loop='Y';
    float discount=1,rType,tPrice=0,mPrice=0,days;
    
    cout<<"Enter sold rooms in first floor : ";
    cin>>sRoom[0];
    cout<<"Enter sold rooms in second floor : ";
    cin>>sRoom[1];
    cout<<"Enter sold rooms in third floor : ";
    cin>>sRoom[2];
    cout<<"Enter sold rooms in fourth floor : ";
    cin>>sRoom[3];
    aRoom[0]=tRoom[0]-sRoom[0];
    aRoom[1]=tRoom[1]-sRoom[1];
    aRoom[2]=tRoom[2]-sRoom[2];
    aRoom[3]=tRoom[3]-sRoom[3];
    cout<<"\n---------------------------------";
    cout<<"\n   WELCOME TO HERA PLACE HOTEL";
    cout<<"\n---------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<aRoom[0]<<" rooms available in first floor"<<endl;
    cout<<aRoom[1]<<" rooms available in first second"<<endl;
    cout<<aRoom[2]<<" rooms available in first third"<<endl;
    cout<<aRoom[3]<<" rooms available in first fourth"<<endl;
    cout<<"\nDo you have the premium membersip?";
    cout<<"\nEnter [Y]Yes or [N]No : ";
    cin>>mem;
    
    while(loop!='N')
    {   
        hotelMembership(mem);
        cout<<"\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------";
        cout<<"\nFloor 1[1 Single Bed] Floor 2[2 Single Bed] Floor 3[1 King Bed] Floor 4[2 King Bed]";
        cout<<"\nEnter Floor Option [1,2,3,4] : ";
        cin>>rType;
        if(rType==1)
        {
        cout<<"How many days would you like to stay at this room? : ";
        cin>>days;
        cout<<"How many rooms would you like to buy? : ";
        cin>>qRoom;
        if(aRoom[0]>=qRoom)
        {
        aRoom[0]-=qRoom;
        tPrice+=qRoom*75*days;
        }
        else
        cout<<"There are only "<<aRoom[0]<<" rooms available,please input available room quantity only";
        }
        if(rType==2)
        {
        cout<<"How many days would you like to stay at this room? : ";
        cin>>days;
        cout<<"How many rooms would you like to buy? : ";
        cin>>qRoom;
        if(aRoom[1]>=qRoom)
        {
        aRoom[1]-=qRoom;
        tPrice+=qRoom*150*days;
        }
        else
        cout<<"There are only "<<aRoom[1]<<" rooms available,please input available room quantity only";
        }
        if(rType==3)
        {
        cout<<"How many days would you like to stay at this room? : ";
        cin>>days;
        cout<<"How many rooms would you like to buy? : ";
        cin>>qRoom;
        if(aRoom[2]>=qRoom)
        {
        aRoom[2]-=qRoom;
        tPrice+=qRoom*150*days;
        }
        else
        cout<<"There are only "<<aRoom[2]<<" rooms available,please input available room quantity only";
        }
        if(rType==4)
        {
        cout<<"How many days would you like to stay at this room? : ";
        cin>>days;  
        cout<<"How many rooms would you like to buy? : ";
        cin>>qRoom;
        if(aRoom[3]>=qRoom)
        {
        tPrice+=qRoom*280*days;
        aRoom[3]-=qRoom;
        }
        else
        cout<<"There are only "<<aRoom[3]<<" rooms available,please input available room quantity only";
        }
        cout<<"\nEnter [Y] to continue buying more rooms or enter [N] to pay for the room : ";
        cin>>loop;
    }
    cout<<"\nTotal price is : RM "<<(tPrice*discount)+mPrice;
    cout<<"\nThank you and enjoy your stay at Hera Place Hotel ";
    
    
}
float hotelMembership(char mem){
    float discount=1,rType,tPrice=0,mPrice=0,days;
    if(mem=='Y')
    {
        return discount*0.8;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\nWould you like to purchase our premium membership for RM 100?";
        cout<<"\nMembership benefits include[Complimentary daily breakfast,High speed wifi,20%total discount]";
        cout<<"\nEnter [Y]Yes or [N]No : ";
        cin>>mem;
        if(mem=='Y')
        {
            cout<<"\nThankyou for purchasing our membership!";
            return mPrice=100;
            return discount*0.8;
        }
    }
    
}
```

The total price is suppose to be 240 instead it came out as 300
[The is what happens when I run the code]

```
Enter sold rooms in first floor : 10
Enter sold rooms in second floor : 10
Enter sold rooms in third floor : 10
Enter sold rooms in fourth floor : 10

---------------------------------
   WELCOME TO HERA PLACE HOTEL
---------------------------------
5 rooms available in first floor
5 rooms available in first second
5 rooms available in first third
0 rooms available in first fourth

Do you have the premium membersip?
Enter [Y]Yes or [N]No : Y

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Floor 1[1 Single Bed] Floor 2[2 Single Bed] Floor 3[1 King Bed] Floor 4[2 King Bed]
Enter Floor Option [1,2,3,4] : 2
How many days would you like to stay at this room? : 1
How many rooms would you like to buy? : 2

Enter [Y] to continue buying more rooms or enter [N] to pay for the room : N

Total price is : RM 300
Thank you and enjoy your stay at Hera Place Hotel
```

Comment: small note: next time when asking a question on stackoverflow.com, in the tags include the programming language you're using. That will help people find their way here more easily and be more clear.

Comment: How can the (second) `return discount*0.8;` ever actually execute when it is *immediately* preceded by `return mPrice=100;`? Can you clarify what you're trying to do with these two return statements?

Answer (score 1):

`float hotelMembership(char mem){` returns a float....

... return value is ignored
        `hotelMembership(mem);`

You need to assign the return value to the variable
`discount = hotelMembership(mem);`

Comment: There's also a problem with two consecutive `return` statements in the `else...` block.